# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'token')

Tags: javascript, vue.js

when i use localStorage i have this error : Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'token').
But my token is here **:**

[image]

Promise is here **:**

[image]

```
        async loginSubmit () {
        const response = axios.post('http://localhost:3000/api/auth/login', {
            email: this.email,
            password: this.password
        });
        localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token);
        console.log(response);
        this.$router.push('actu');

    },
```

Can you help me ? please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Axios returns a promise, you need to await the request:

```js
const response = await axios.post(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using axios, it returns a promise. That's why you have this error. You have to use async await to wait for axios to respond